# How to manipulate Session, Request and Response for test in play2.0

Tags: playframework-2.0

Hi I had an authentication service which works on Request (some Header-Data and Cookie), Response (to set or delete a cookie) and session (Store userId and rememberMe-information).

In play 1.x it was easy to fake Request, Response, Cookie and Session. It could be easily set with `Session.current().set(new Session())`. In play 2.0 this doesn't work anymore.

How can I add a cookie to a request? How could I manipulate the session? I saw there exists FakeApplication and FakeRequest but I didn't get it, how to work with them.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to do it similar to play1.x. The central point is the `Context`. Furthermore you must create a `DummyRequest` which implements the methods you need. Then it's possible to create the following

```
final Request request = new DummyRequest();
Context.current.set(new Context(request, new HashMap <String, String>(), 
        new HashMap <String, String>()));
```

in your test you can get `Context.current().session()`, `Context.current().response()` or `Context.current().request()`.

You can see here an [test-example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~opensource21/permsec/trunk/view/head:/psec/test/de/ppi/psec/services/AuthenticationServiceTest.java).

Comment: Instead of implementing a whole dummy request, it would probably be easier to use a mock library. +1 anyway for the `Context.current.set()` answer.

Comment: Yes a mock-library would be the cleaner approach. Had some trouble last time with dependencies, so I choose in the whole test to write my mocks manually.

Answer (score 14):

It was not ready for Play 2.0, but in Play 2.1 (and in current master) you’ll be able to write:

```java
fakeRequest(GET, "/foo")
    .withSession("bar", "baz")
    .withCookies(cookie("bah", "toto"));
```

Comment: If I call this, will I get it with `Context.current().request()`? Must there a route for the URL? I mean a FakeRequest only is worthless because it's not an instance of Request :-(

Comment: Yes, every URL must have a route. Inside an action you can retrieve the current session by using the [session()](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/index.html) controller’s method.

Comment: Sorry but I try to test a module, so I don't have a route. For the test this isn't needed. Furthermore I would appreciate if don't must create a controller just for the test. I tried fakeRequest and then Context.current().request(), but get a RuntimeException. So I still doesn't understand what fakeRequest do.

Comment: Actually you only need to have a route if you’re using the `routeAndCall` helper. But you can also directly use `callAction` to avoid the route definition.