# Play 2 framework testing simulate session and POST?

Tags: testing, post, playframework, playframework-2.0

When running a web test like this

```
@Test
public void runInBrowser() {
    running(testServer(3333),  HtmlUnitDriver.class, new Callback<TestBrowser>() {
        public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
           browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333"); 
           assertThat(browser.$("#title").getTexts().get(0)).isEqualTo("Hello Guest");
           browser.$("a").click();
           assertThat(browser.url()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:3333/Coco");
           assertThat(browser.$("#title", 0).getText()).isEqualTo("Hello Coco");
        }
    });
}
```

How can one pass sessions values while using this kind of testing and how can one simulate a POST? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

These are Selenium tests with [FluentLenium](https://github.com/FluentLenium/FluentLenium). Since you test with a browser you must use an HTML form with method POST to make a POST request.

```
browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333" + routes.Login.login().url());//example for reverse route, alternatively use something like "http://localhost:3333/login"
browser.fill("#password").with("secret");
browser.fill("#username").with("aUsername");
browser.submit("#signin");//trigger submit button on the form
//after finished request: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/java/play/test/TestBrowser.html
browser.getCookies(); //read only cookies
```

Maybe you don't want to make test with a browser but instead with HTTP you can use [FakeRequests](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/java/play/test/FakeRequest.html):

```
import static controllers.routes.ref.Application;
import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat;
import static play.mvc.Http.Status.OK;
import static play.mvc.Http.Status.UNAUTHORIZED;
import static play.test.Helpers.*;

import play.libs.WS;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.test.FakeRequest;

public class SoTest {
  @Test
  public void testInServer() {
    running(testServer(3333), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Fixtures.loadAll();//you may have to fill your database you have to program this yourself
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("userName", "aUsername");
            parameters.put("password", "secret");
            FakeRequest fakeRequest = new FakeRequest().withSession("key", "value").withCookies(name, value, maxAge, path, domain, secure, httpOnly).withFormUrlEncodedBody(parameters);
            Result result = callAction(Application.signIn(), fakeRequest);
            int responseCode = status(result);
            assertThat(responseCode).isEqualTo(OK);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Also check out this answer: [How to manipulate Session, Request and Response for test in play2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381354/how-to-manipulate-session-request-and-response-for-test-in-play2-0)