# Play! Framework 2.20 - Issue with reverse router "ref" and functional testing

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have an issue with my reverse router in Play! 2.2.0

I would like to test a method from my controller as describe in [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaFunctionalTest) like this:

```
@Test
public void testIsSessionSpeaker_true() throws Exception {
    // the action
    Result result = callAction( controllers.routes.ref.UsersController.isSessionSpeaker(workshop.workshopSession.get(0)),
                                fakeRequest().withSession("uuid", "123456"));
    // test after action
}
```

When I run my test I get the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.UsersController.isSessionSpeaker(workshop.workshopSession.get(0)),
^
symbol: method isSessionSpeaker(WorkshopSession)
location: variable UsersController of type ReverseUsersController
1 error
```

The method `isSessionSpeaker` I would like to test is not accessible with a route, so I can't use `route(fakeRequest(PUT, "something"))` and the method need a session, so I can't just "call it" like `UsersController.isSessionSpeaker(...)` or I get a `There is no HTTP Context available from here.`

The issue is not from my intellij because I compile and execute my tests with the activator.

After reading half the web I tried some other way to write the ref as:

```
controllers.WorkshopManager.routes.ref.UsersController.isSessionSpeaker(...)
controllers.WorkshopManager.routes.UsersController.isSessionSpeaker(...)
controllers.routes.UsersController.isSessionSpeaker(...)
routes.ref.UsersController.isSessionSpeaker(...)
```

I'm stuck !!
If you want to see the all code, I pushed it in my git repo [here](https://github.com/ychartois/WorkshopManager)

Thx in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got one part of the answer, the [Issue #969](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/969) hide me the real problem (thx Eclipse to show me it!).

Reverse router (as the name suggest...) allow to access method which have a route. Since `isSessionSpeaker(...)` is a method of my controller which is not part of my router I can't use the `callAction` to test my method.

Now I just have to find a way to test a method in my controller which is not part of my router when you need a session, but it's an other question...

Comment: In case someone read this, the easiest solution I found to fake the session in that case is: `public void fakeSession() {
       Http.Context.current.set(new Http.Context( 1l, mock(RequestHeader.class), mock(Http.Request.class), new HashMap<String, String>(),
               new HashMap <String, String>(), new HashMap <String, Object>()));
       Http.Context.current().session().put("uuid", UUID);
    }` with the help of that [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381354/how-to-manipulate-session-request-and-response-for-test-in-play2-0), it use mokito and it's works just fine!